# Trying to access a div from an anchor with a jQuery function using "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsap

I'm trying to animate a `div` inside of a link tag.

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#">INFO <div></div></a></li>
```

I'm using a jQuery function like so to figure out which of the links is being interacted with.

```
function slideMenu(e) {

  if(e.type === "mouseover"){
    console.log("mouseover");
    //console.log(this > bgColor);

    // TweenMax.to($(this > div) , 1, {height:200});
  }
  else if(e.type === "mouseout"){
    console.log("mouseout");
  }
  else if(e.type === "click"){
    console.log("click");
  }

}

$(".menu a").click(slideMenu);

$(".menu a").mouseover(slideMenu);

$(".menu a").mouseout(slideMenu);
```

I'm trying to use greensock and grab the `div` inside of the anchor tag and change the height, but it doesn't seem to be giving me access to that `div` tag.

Comment: Try `$(this).find('> div')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` is a child of the element binded with `$(this)`.
You can use `.find()` to target it.

```js
$("a").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find("div").html("I'm here!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">INFO <div>Click me.</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@evolutionxbox put the answer in the commments, use :

```
$(this).find('> div')
```

Be sure that you have a `.menu` class in a parent of `<a>` element

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could simply add an id to that div and find it that way.

If not, you could use `.children('div')`